# How to flip a clip in iMove 10.1.9 for OSX

Tags: mac, imovie

It seems I can find an answer to this question for every version of iMovie except 10.1.9. There is no Adjust menu in the upper menu bar. There is no Advanced Tools option in the preferences. The only menu that appears when I drop the clip over another is the green screen/cutaway menu. I'm assured that all the advanced tools you need will simply appear when you need them -- ain't happening.

I simply want to flip a clip shot upside down on a GoPro. Surely this is within the capabilities of iMovie?

Answer (score 0):

To the right of the CROP menu, there are options to rotate left and rotate right.